# Use ansible filters to produce list of hosts based on conditions and defaults

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I have written this a simplified example but it should be enough as a minimal reproducible code. I want to be able to generate a list of hosts from my inventory file based on 2 rules.

1. The host belongs to a group called `cdsre`
2. The host either has a attribute `foo` defined with a value of `baz` **OR** the host doesn't define an attribute `foo`

I have been at this for a few hours and can achieve this with a long winded jinja2 string loop that uses an `if` expression with a side effect which i think is pretty ugly. However I cant help think this should be achievable using just jinja filters.

**sample inventory**

```yaml
all:
  children:
    cdsre:
      children:
        ovh_vm:
          hosts:
            ovh-vm[1:3]:
            ovh-vm[6:7]:
              foo: baz
        oracle_vm:
          hosts:
            oracle-vm[1:3]:
              foo: bar
            oracle-vm[4:5]:
              foo: baz
```

**Playbook**

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        some_servers: |
          {% set servers = [] %}
          {% for host in groups['cdsre'] %}
          {% set foo = hostvars[host]['foo'] | default('baz', true) %}
          {% if foo == 'baz' %}
          {% if servers.append(hostvars[host]['inventory_hostname']) %}{% endif %}
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
          {{ servers }}
        foo_matched_servers: "{{ groups['cdsre'] | map('extract', hostvars) | selectattr('foo', 'defined') | selectattr('foo', '==', 'baz') | map(attribute='inventory_hostname') | list}}"
    - debug:
        var: some_servers
    - debug:
        var: foo_matched_servers
```

**OUTPUT**

```
PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Tuesday 10 January 2023  23:57:00 +0000 (0:00:00.073)       0:00:00.073 *******
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Tuesday 10 January 2023  23:57:01 +0000 (0:00:00.885)       0:00:00.958 *******
ok: [localhost] => {
    "some_servers": [
        "ovh-vm1",
        "ovh-vm2",
        "ovh-vm3",
        "ovh-vm6",
        "ovh-vm7",
        "oracle-vm4",
        "oracle-vm5"
    ]
}

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Tuesday 10 January 2023  23:57:01 +0000 (0:00:00.061)       0:00:01.019 *******
ok: [localhost] => {
    "foo_matched_servers": [
        "ovh-vm6",
        "ovh-vm7",
        "oracle-vm4",
        "oracle-vm5"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

Tuesday 10 January 2023  23:57:01 +0000 (0:00:00.062)       0:00:01.082 ******* 
===============================================================================
set_fact ---------------------------------------------------------------- 0.89s
debug ------------------------------------------------------------------- 0.12s
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
total ------------------------------------------------------------------- 1.01s
```

So i can produce the list of hosts matching condition 1 but What I cant seem to work out is how I can capture in a single fact the hosts that match condition 1 and condition 2. Is this even possible? or do i need to write an additional fact to capture the hosts matching condition 2 then join both facts (this also feels a bit long winded)

Comment: You should omit *`true`* as the second argument in *`default('baz', true)`*.  Setting the second argument in [*default*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.default) to *`true`* means *'use default with variables that evaluate to false'*. An empty string also evaluates to *`false`*. But, you don't want to include an empty string. You said you want either *foo* undefined or *baz*. An empty string means *foo* is defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are more options:

1. Use Jinja to create a string with a valid YAML list and convert the string to the list

Declare the variables below

```yaml
  my_hosts_str: |
    [
    {% for host in groups.cdsre %}
    {% if hostvars[host]['foo']|default('baz') == 'baz' %}
    {{ host }},
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    ]
  my_hosts: "{{ my_hosts_str|from_yaml }}"
```

gives the valid YAML list in the string *my_hosts_str*

```yaml
  my_hosts_str: |-
    [
    ovh-vm1,
    ovh-vm2,
    ovh-vm3,
    ovh-vm6,
    ovh-vm7,
    oracle-vm4,
    oracle-vm5,
    ]
```

gives the expected result. Converts the string to the list.

```yaml
  my_hosts:
  - ovh-vm1
  - ovh-vm2
  - ovh-vm3
  - ovh-vm6
  - ovh-vm7
  - oracle-vm4
  - oracle-vm5
```

Example of a playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    my_hosts_str: |
      [
      {% for host in groups.cdsre %}
      {% if hostvars[host]['foo']|default('baz') == 'baz' %}
      {{ host }},
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      ]
    my_hosts: "{{ my_hosts_str|from_yaml }}"

  tasks:

    - block:
        - debug:
            var: my_hosts_str
        - debug:
            var: my_hosts
      run_once: true
```

---

2. Use filters to create the variable *my_hosts*.

Declare the variables below, e.g. in *group_vars/all*

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all
csdr_foo_und: "{{ groups.cdsre|map('extract', hostvars)|
                               selectattr('foo', 'undefined')|
                               map(attribute='inventory_hostname') }}"
csdr_foo_baz: "{{ groups.cdsre|map('extract', hostvars)|
                               selectattr('foo', 'defined')|
                               selectattr('foo', '==', 'baz')|
                               map(attribute='inventory_hostname') }}"
my_hosts: "{{ csdr_foo_baz + csdr_foo_und }}"
```

gives the list of hosts in the group *csdr* with undefined *foo*

```yaml
  csdr_foo_und:
  - ovh-vm1
  - ovh-vm2
  - ovh-vm3
```

gives the list of hosts in the group *csdr* with *foo* equal to *baz*

```yaml
  csdr_foo_baz:
  - ovh-vm6
  - ovh-vm7
  - oracle-vm4
  - oracle-vm5
```

gives the expected result. Concatenates the lists *csdr_foo_und* and *csdr_foo_baz*

```yaml
  my_hosts:
  - oracle-vm4
  - oracle-vm5
  - ovh-vm1
  - ovh-vm2
  - ovh-vm3
  - ovh-vm6
  - ovh-vm7
```

Example of a playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - block:
        - debug:
            var: csdr_foo_und
        - debug:
            var: csdr_foo_baz
        - debug:
            var: my_hosts|sort
      run_once: true
```

---

3. Create a new group *my_group*

Use the inventory plugin *constructed*. See

```bash
shell> ansible-doc -t inventory ansible.builtin.constructed
```

For example, create the project below for testing

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── inventory
│   ├── 01-hosts.yml
│   └── 02-constructed.yml
└── pb.yml

1 directory, 4 files
```

```ini
shell> cat ansible.cfg 
[defaults]
gathering = explicit
inventory = $PWD/inventory
retry_files_enabled = false
stdout_callback = yaml
```

```yaml
shell> cat inventory/01-hosts.yml 
all:
  children:
    cdsre:
      children:
        ovh_vm:
          hosts:
            ovh-vm[1:3]:
            ovh-vm[6:7]:
              foo: baz
        oracle_vm:
          hosts:
            oracle-vm[1:3]:
              foo: bar
            oracle-vm[4:5]:
              foo: baz
```

Create a new group *my_group*

```yaml
shell> cat inventory/02-constructed.yml 
plugin: ansible.builtin.constructed
use_vars_plugins: true
use_extra_vars: true
groups:
  # host belongs to group 'cdsre' and
  # foo is either undefined or 'baz'
  my_group: group_names is contains 'cdsre' and
            foo|default('baz') == 'baz'
```

Either reference the group *groups.my_group* or use it in *hosts*

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: groups.my_group
      run_once: true

- hosts: my_group
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_play_hosts_all
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [ovh-vm1] => 
  groups.my_group:
  - ovh-vm1
  - ovh-vm2
  - ovh-vm3
  - ovh-vm6
  - ovh-vm7
  - oracle-vm4
  - oracle-vm5

PLAY [my_group] ******************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [ovh-vm1] => 
  ansible_play_hosts_all:
  - ovh-vm1
  - ovh-vm2
  - ovh-vm3
  - ovh-vm6
  - ovh-vm7
  - oracle-vm4
  - oracle-vm5

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
ovh-vm1: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple way to achieve that - using [`add_host`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/add_host_module.html) module you can define a group dynamically without changing the inventory plugin or defining any additional variables. This will also allow to run the subsequent plays specifically on the hosts that match the criteria:

```yaml
# playbook.yaml
---
- name: Add hosts to a special group based on condition
  hosts: all
  connection: local # could be your own choice
  gather_facts: false # could be your own choice
  tasks:
    - name: Add host to my_group
      add_host:
        name: "{{ hostvars[item].inventory_hostname }}"
        group: my_group
      when:
        - hostvars[item].inventory_hostname in groups.cdsre
        - hostvars[item].foo is defined and hostvars[item].foo == 'baz'
          or hostvars[item].foo is not defined
      loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all }}"

    - name: List the hosts matching criteria
      debug:
        var: groups['my_group']
      run_once: true
```

Using your inventory as an example, this produces:

```yaml
TASK [List the hosts matching criteria] ***************************************
ok: [ovh-vm1] => 
  groups['my_group']:
  - ovh-vm1
  - ovh-vm2
  - ovh-vm3
  - ovh-vm6
  - ovh-vm7
  - oracle-vm4
  - oracle-vm5
```

If you're not going to change the name of the group you want to select the hosts from, you can simplify the `when` condition by running the above play directly on `cdsre` group (I also simplified the `foo` variable comparison like you did):

```yaml
# playbook.yaml
---
- name: Add hosts to a special group based on condition
  hosts: cdsre
  connection: local # could be your own choice
  gather_facts: false # could be your own choice
  tasks:
    - name: Add host to my_group
      add_host:
        name: "{{ hostvars[item].inventory_hostname }}"
        group: my_group
      when: hostvars[item].foo | default('baz') == 'baz'
      loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all }}"

    - name: List the hosts matching criteria
      debug:
        var: groups['my_group']
      run_once: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 worked for me. This answer is slight variation showing how to expand on that option. 100% of the credit to Vladimir, though. Could not have come up with this without him.

In my case, my inventory had host names with

```
this_host_is_manager_01.example.com:
  os_node_roles: [ 'cluster_manager' ]
```

defined for certain hosts. I wanted a list of said hosts. This did it:

```
os_manager_str: |
  [
    {% for host in ansible_play_hosts %} # I already had hosts selected
    {% if 'cluster_manager' in hostvars[host]['os_node_roles'] %} # secret sauce
    {{ host|regex_replace('\..*', '') }}, # convert FQDN to short hostname
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  ]
os_manager_nodes: "{{ os_manager_str|from_yaml }}"
```

The secret sauce for this selection was an `in` clause.

Thank you so much, Vladimir: you seem to have quite a penchant for these sorts of things.